# History of Group Actions as their own Structures

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, math-history

I'm interested in when (and how) the modern idea of a group action developed and how group actions became their own algebraic structures.

As far as i can tell in the 19th century group actions were much more implicit than they are today and were strongly tied to the group itself, as a subgroup of a permutation group. But the way group actions are presented today (at the very least as they were presented to me) is much more axiomatic and considers group actions and groups as separate algebraic structures.

When and how did this change (if it changed at all) and how did group actions become so important?

Comment: That question is off-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: The question of "how" something in math changed ususally has the same answer: people realized a recurring pattern, and then said "hey, this notion keeps coming up, and is a general feature. I can make an abstraction of this". This is of course motivated by very concrete examples (symmetric groups, diffeomorphism groups etc). Some people (Bourbaki) take the abstraction so far as to start from scratch: define an action of a mere set on another set. Then introduce structure one at a time (define it for magmas, then monoids, groups etc). The question of "when" is interesting, but off-topic here.

Comment: The math-history tag is a trap; although this is a very interesting question and I hope you ask it in HSM as others suggested.

Comment: As the mods suggested I have now posted the question in [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15129/history-of-group-actions-as-their-own-structures)